# About the cookies/localstorage/cache in cobalt

Tags: cobalt

It seemed cobalt can support `cookies`, `localstorage`, `cache`, so what's the the max size of cookies for each site? What's the max size of localstorage for each site? What's max size of cache for each site? Is there a total size limit for cookies, for localstorage and for cache separately? Is there a way to set them separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies and Local Storage are stored together in an in-memory SQLite database and then serialized and saved into SbStorage. There's a 4MB internal limit on the size of that total storage which isn't currently configurable.

Cache is only used for the splash screen right now, and has no limit enforced by Cobalt.